# MongoDB - intersecting objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

### Scenario

Given I have a document following the following general `Person` structure:

```
{ "name" : "John", "age" : 18, "gender" : "male" }
{ "name" : "Dave", "age" : 26, "gender" : "male" }
{ "name" : "Jane", "age" : 18, "gender" : "female" }
```

And I have the following `Movie` structure :

```
{ "name" : "A great movie", "suitableFor" : { "gender" : "female" } }
{ "name" : "Another movie", "suitableFor" : { "age" : 18 } }
{ "name" : "Super-nice movie", "suitableFor" : { "gender" : "male" } }
```

### Problem outline

Let's say I have the female Jane, age 18. Now I want to find all the movies suitable to her, which would be "A great movie" since it's suitable for females and "Another movie" since it's suitable for people who are exactly 18 years old.

### Possible solution

**Aggregation Framework**: Project all attributes of `suitableFor` and Jane to arrays of strings, something like `["name:Jane","age:18","gender:female"]` and for "Another movie" `["age:18"]`, then using `$isSubSet` and finally `$match`. This seems **really** hacky to me.

Life would just be easier if one could do something like `$isSubSet` objects, which would sort of create a reverse query; `suitableFor` would have to `$match` the given `Person` (Jane in this case).

An **important information**: This is a multi-tenancy application with an application-level schema defined by the tenant, so there is no way to know the attributes to query in advance.

How would one go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be optimal but I guess you could get some pointers from this. One approach you can take with the aggregation framework is compose a pipeline with a couple of **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** stages that join the person collection from 
the movies collection based on two fields i.e. `gender` and `age`. You can then filter the documents using **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** first then **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**.

The following example demonstrates this intuition:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "person",
            "localField": "suitableFor.gender",
            "foreignField": "gender",
            "as": "suitableForBasedOnGender"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "person",
            "localField": "suitableFor.age",
            "foreignField": "age",
            "as": "suitableForBasedOnAge"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$suitableForBasedOnGender", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$suitableForBasedOnAge", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "$or": [
                { "suitableForBasedOnAge.name": "Jane" },
                { "suitableForBasedOnGender.name": "Jane" }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aeca12815a2dcda0764b23"),
        "name" : "A great movie",
        "suitableFor" : {
            "gender" : "female"
        },
        "suitableForBasedOnGender" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58aec9ee815a2dcda0764b22"),
            "name" : "Jane",
            "age" : 18,
            "gender" : "female"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aeca12815a2dcda0764b24"),
        "name" : "Another movie",
        "suitableFor" : {
            "age" : 18
        },
        "suitableForBasedOnAge" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58aec9ee815a2dcda0764b22"),
            "name" : "Jane",
            "age" : 18,
            "gender" : "female"
        }
    }
]
```

---

You may then tweak the query in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline for different parameter combinations using **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** and **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)** [logical operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) e.g. get the movies suitable for a person name "Jane" AND age 18:

```
{ 
    "$match": { 
        "$and": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    { "suitableForBasedOnAge.name": "Jane" },
                    { "suitableForBasedOnGender.name": "Jane" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "$or": [
                    { "suitableForBasedOnAge.age": 18 },
                    { "suitableForBasedOnGender.name": 18 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which would return the only document in the results array:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58aeca12815a2dcda0764b24"),
    "name" : "Another movie",
    "suitableFor" : {
        "age" : 18
    },
    "suitableForBasedOnAge" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aec9ee815a2dcda0764b22"),
        "name" : "Jane",
        "age" : 18,
        "gender" : "female"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @chridam! Thanks for taking your time to write such a comprehensive answer. It's a neat way to do it, however it comes short on something I forgot to mention in the original post (I'll edit it in a moment); the attributes in `suitableFor` can change at any time, and in this case I ned it for a multi-tenancy application with mutable application-level schemas, so unfortunately directly referencing the attributes is impossible unless it's done in runtime which I presume would make a significant hit on performance. I'll look more into the concepts you used. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :) Again, as I pointed out earlier the solution may not be optimal as it's not dynamic and you are right, creating the pipelines dynamically during runtime may incur some performance penalties but I guess you can take away one or two pointers in getting the recommender system right via MongoDB. Good luck!